# Getting Inbox mail item from multiple email ID configured in outlook

Tags: vb.net, vba, outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-2007

I am working on outlook add in ,I am configured three accounts in outlook based upon selection of email ID i want to process the Inbox item for archive.
In 2010 my code is working perfect but in outlook 2007 getting problem.

Based upon the selection i am getting Inbox item but in 2007 its giving error

```
             Dim mailID As String = selectedmailID
            inBoxItems = ns.Folders(mailID).Folders("Inbox").Items        //error
            inBoxItems = inBoxItems.Restrict("[Unread] = true")
```

How I resolve this problem ?
  Devlelopment system contain outlook 2010 but testing system contain otlook 2007
  I has changed reference also but its not working.

Is there settings from outlook ?
plz help me

Answer (score 0):

What is the exact error message? 
Why not use ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFiolderInbox)?